# Spring kafka become zombie when kafka broker restarted

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using kafka with spring-starter-parent version 2.6.6

Recently, my kafka client become zombie when kafka broker restarted ( we have 3 brokers, and it was a rolling restart )

It is required a restart on kafka client so it can resume its activity.

log are below :

```
o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Failed authentication with broker_server (Authentication failed: Invalid username or password)
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Connection to node 2 (broker_server) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1125142585, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password

o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] An authentication error occurred in the heartbeat thread

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password

o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Failed authentication with broker_server_03 Authentication failed: Invalid username or password)
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Connection to node 2147483644 (broker_server_03) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Authentication/Authorization Exception and no authExceptionRetryInterval set

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Fatal consumer exception; stopping container
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Revoke previously assigned partitions group-0, group-1
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-registration-group: partitions revoked: [group-0, group-1]
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Group coordinator xxx (id: 2147483644 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be 
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-registration-group-1, groupId=xxx-registration-group] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-xxx-registration-group-1 unregistered
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-registration-group: Consumer stopped
c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

No custom configuration on client-side, mostly are default.

How to handle this event, so my consumer can continue the process without manually restart it ??

Comment: By default, Consumers should remain polling until a metadata refresh. Maybe try updating your client version

Comment: `o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Fatal consumer exception; stopping container` -  before this log, there will be another log which logs the actual fatal exception (e.g. `NoOffsetForPartitionException`, `AuthenticationException`, etc.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell, I updated my post, any idea why it is throwing invalid credentials when broker get restarted ?